# Logging to Azure Diagnostics from console\web app

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-cloud-services

There are a bunch of resources online ([example](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/10/22/logging-with-log4net-and-azure-diagnostics-on-web-and-worker-roles/)) that describe this for cloud services. Is the same possible for console\web applications? It seems that this is quite specific to worker\web roles. I tried porting to console application but it didnt work for some reason. I've added diagnostics config xml and added system.diagnostics trace listener (copied from the cloud service), I've also installed the same nuget packages, but probably cloud service initialization method does initialize something i'm not aware about.

Just to be clear, I'm talking about applications inside vms, not paas offerings

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(...);` in your Azure Web App or Console App deployed as a WebJob (or any other app deployed to Azure App Service), by enabling Application Logging and setting the level of information you want:

1. Go to your Web App.
2. Go to Monitoring / Diagnostics logs.
3. Enable Application Logging and configure it.

[image: Application Logging]

This article may also be useful: https://stackify.com/azure-app-service-log-files/

Comment: updated my question, this is not what I'm looking for.